# Changing row border color introduces some strange cell-shifting

Tags: css, javafx, colors, tableview

I change the style of some of my table's rows in order to do some highlighting:

```
table.setRowFactory(tv -> new TableRow<TableBean>() {

        @Override
        public void updateItem(TableBean item, boolean empty) {

        super.updateItem(item, empty);
        if (item == null) {
            setStyle("");
        } else if (item.getComparisonElement().isMarker()) {
            setStyle("-fx-border-color: red;");
        } else {
            setStyle("");
        }
        }
    });
```

This works, but I have some cells "shifted" as an unwanted side effect:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect having some rows with a border and others without is messing up the layout.

The way the default stylesheet, modena.css, implements most border effects is to actually use "nested backgrounds". The idea is to paint one solid background color with no insets, and then paint a second background color with a positive inset. E.g. if you paint a red background with zero insets, and then a background in the default background color with an inset of 1 pixel on each side, it will create the effect of a 1-pixel wide red border. (Anecdotally - I haven't any real evidence for this - this technique has better performance than using an actual border setting.) The advantage in this use case is that adding a (real) border will change the layout of the table row as space is allocated to the border, whereas changing the background color makes no difference to the layout.

So try this instead:

```
table.setRowFactory(tv -> new TableRow<TableBean>() {

    @Override
    public void updateItem(TableBean item, boolean empty) {

        super.updateItem(item, empty);
        if (item == null) {
            setStyle("");
        } else if (item.getComparisonElement().isMarker()) {
            setStyle("-fx-background-color: red, -fx-background;"+
                     "-fx-background-insets: 0, 1;");
        } else {
            setStyle("");
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: awsome, Works like a charm! Could you explain how you solved this without touching the "no-highlight" rows?

Comment: @kerner1000 Added a brief explanation.